# PHP multiple drop down select

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Hoping someone can help me with this... I have a program I am writing in PHP and ajax that has multiple select boxes and with each select populates the next drop down box. I need to $_Post multiple options and use these to run a mysql query.
Here is my layout:

I have:

```
<div class="row">
<label>Camera:</label><br/>
<select name="camera" id="camera-list" class="demoInputBox" 
onChange="getCod(this.value);">
<option value="">Select Camera</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="row">
<label>Codec:</label><br/>
<select name="codec" id="codec-list" class="demoInputBox" 
onChange="getFra(this.value);">
<option value="">Select Codec</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="row">
<label>Framerate:</label><br/>
<select name="framerate" id="framerate-list" class="demoInputBox">
<option value="">Select Framerate</option>
</select>
</div>
```

with function:

```
function getCod(val) {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "get_codec.php",
data:'camID='+val,
success: function(data){
    $("#codec-list").html(data);
}
});
}

function getFra(val) {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "get_framerate.php",
data:'codID='+val,
success: function(data){
    $("#framerate-list").html(data);
}
});
}
```

how do I retrieve both Post values to use in a mysql query

example mysql query i am trying to run:

```
<?php
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
if(!empty($_POST["camID"]["codID"])) {
$query ="SELECT framerate FROM cam_stat WHERE (cam_id = '" . $_POST["camID"] 
. "') and ( codec = '" . $_POST["codID"] . "')";
$results = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
?>
<option value="">Select Framerate</option>
<?php
foreach($results as $framerate) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $framerate["ID"]; ?>"><?php echo 
$framerate["framerate"]; ?></option>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

mysql table sample:

```
ID, cam_id, resolution, codec, framerate, compression, datarate
```

Note: in this table there can be multiple codecs that are the same for each cam_id, I am trying to get the next select box to show the possible framerates where the cam_id equals the selected and the codec also equals the selected.

I am new to posting on these kind of threads so forgive me if my question doesnt make since... i am trying to retrieve the post of camid and codid to insert into my query... any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: in function `getFra` before `$.ajax`, add  `var data = {camId : $("#camera-list").val(), codID : $("codec-list").val()};` and replace `data:'codID='+val,` with `data : data`

Comment: @Cemal How does this pass the value of the selected option into the codID? I have onChange=getFra(this.value); passing the value of the selected option.

Comment: the value is retrieved via `$("codec-list").val()`. Your code, `onChange=getFra(this.value);` however is not cross browser compliant. (It should have been `onChange=getFra(this.getAttribute("value"));`) however using `$("codec-list").val()` eliminates the requirement for it.

Comment: @Cemal I have changed my function to: function getFra(val) {
       var data = {camID : $("#camera-list").val(), codID : $("codec-list").val()};
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "get_framerate.php",
 data: data,
 success: function(data){
  $("#framerate-list").html(data);
 }
 });
}

Comment: @Cemal and mysql query to:    <?php
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
if(!empty($_POST["camID"]["codID"])) {
 $query ="SELECT * FROM cam_stat WHERE (cam_id = '" . $_POST["camID"] . "') and (ID = '" . $_POST["codID"] . "')";
 $results = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
?>
<option value="">Select Framerate</option>
<?php
 foreach($results as $framerate) {
?>
 <option value="<?php echo $framerate["ID"]; ?>"><?php echo $framerate["framerate"]; ?></option>
<?php
 }
}
?>

Comment: @Cemal This is leaving my next select box empty... what am i doing wrong?

Comment: This is wrong. `if(!empty($_POST["camID"]["codID"]))` it should have been `if(!empty($_POST["camID"]) && !empty($_POST["codID"]))`

Comment: @Cemal Thank you! I was able to figure this out and my code is working as expected!

Comment: One last advice from me. Use prepared statements in your queries. Any value passed to `$_POST["camID"]` or `$_POST["codID"]` will be appended to your sql query thus prone to sql injection.